# In an ANgular 14 shared libary, how do I create an index.ts file to export everything from a directory?

Tags: angular, export, shared-libraries, angular14

I'm using Angular 14 and building a shared library.  I have this project structure

```
+ projects  
    + my-lib
        - package.json
        + src
            - public-api.ts
            + lib
                + helpers
                    - index.ts
                    - my-first-helper.ts
                    - my-second-helper.ts
                    ...
```

In "public_api.ts" I have

```
export * from './lib/helpers';
```

and in helpers/index.ts I have

```
export * from './my-first-helper';
export * from './my-second-helper';
```

My question is, every time I add a new file to the "helpers" directory, I have to edit my "index.ts" to explicitly include it.  Is there a way I can author my "index.ts" file to just export everything in each file in my "helpers" directory?

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you can do: `export * from '.';`

Comment: I gave that a whirl, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Hmm. You may just have to add each and every file you want to export from.

Comment: may want to look into something like [barrelsby](https://github.com/bencoveney/barrelsby) or [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eliostruyf.vscode-typescript-exportallmodules)

Comment: One possible solution is to use _moduleAliases to include files and which is better than adding every new file in the code. Just use the plugin to package JSON files and enjoy the code
https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Typescript is just an superset language. When compiled it will be Javascript, and Javascript needs an [entry point](https://livebook.manning.com/concept/javascript/entry-point) for all modules that needs to be interpreted by Node.js. When compiling, Node first searchs for package.json, if not finds, will lookup for index.js for default.
A module can be a single or multiple files, Node.js doesnt have to known about your software internal structure, Node only needs to knows about the imports (using the require keyword) on modules.

### BUT

You can automate the process. Its possible to create a script, that manage your index.ts always when a file is added ou removed from your directory. Or use libraries, such as ([create-ts-index](https://github.com/imjuni/create-ts-index))